# How to allow and get Memoji Stickers in a text field

Tags: ios, swift, ios-stickers

I'm trying to use Memoji Stickers on my app, but neither UITextField or TextField from SwiftUI displays them on the keyboard. How can I make them show up, and how do I retrieve them afterwards?

I tried different text input traits, but had no success. I even tried using the Twitter keyboard option, because the stickers work in the Twitter app, but it was to no avail.

[Here's a picture of how it shows up for me in apps that support it, like WhatsApp, Telegram and Twitter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A638x.jpg)

Comment: You need to create a "keyboard extension". Maybe see https://stackoverflow.com/a/37019342/95309 - Also they're called "Stickers" on iOS, this will help you find more appropriate resources. And mind, it's a LOT of work to support this (custom keyboard, custom input fields, custom rendering). It's not something you can easily support out of the box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So... how you can get it is to implement the paste method on the view controller where your textfield/view is.

Then you can grab the image from the pasteboard. Basically

Objective-C

```
UIImage *image = [[UIPasteboard generalPasteboard] image];
```

or Swift

```
let image = UIPasteboard.general.image
```

Which will let you find the UIImage then you can wrap it in

Objective-c
   NSAttributedString *memojiStrong = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithAttributedString: image];

Swift

```
let memojiString = NSAttributedString(attachment: image)
```

This will let you add it as a string to whatever you need to add it to.
You can find a little more for the image -> String if you want to save it for an image: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/system/how-to-insert-images-into-an-attributed-string-with-nstextattachment

and the poster for some credit to get me this far: 
https://www.reddit.com/r/iOSProgramming/comments/cuz3ut/memoji_in_chat/ey4onqg/?context=3

Comment: thanks for your answer.  what I'm observing is that when you select a Memoji it is automatically added to the pasteboard.  but when I access pasteboard.image it returns nil.  how would I otherwise paste the Memoji to the pasteboard?

Comment: @alionthego you need to at least access the general pasteboard as I do in the answer then go for the images. Just doing the images has always yielded nil for me as well. There’s no shortcuts to what I’ve written.

Comment: can you show how exactly to get the UIImage from the pasteboard UIPasteboard.general.image using swift.  Because that file should be a UIImage file but it's empty

Answer (score 1):

set the "allowsEditingTextAttributes" property to YES in UITextField.

Comment: The memoji stickers appear now on the keyboard now, but how can I retrieve them?

Comment: has anybody figured out how to get the sticker from the pasteboard?

Comment: You receive it by overriding the setter of the "attributedText" property of the text-field and then receive it via the TextAttachment objects of the attributed text.

Answer (score 0):

For RxSwift:

```
 textView.rx.attributedText.subscribe(onNext: { [weak self] attributeString in
        guard let attributeString = attributeString else { return }

        attributeString.enumerateAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.attachment, in: NSRange(location: 0, length: attributeString.length), options: [], using: {(value,range,_) -> Void in
            if (value is NSTextAttachment) {
                let attachment: NSTextAttachment? = (value as? NSTextAttachment)
                var image: UIImage?

                if ((attachment?.image) != nil) {
                    image = attachment?.image
                } else {
                    image = attachment?.image(forBounds: (attachment?.bounds)!, textContainer: nil, characterIndex: range.location)
                }

                guard let pasteImage = image else { return }

                guard let pngData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(pasteImage) else { return }
                guard let pngImage = UIImage(data: pngData) else { return }

                guard let attachmentImage = OutgoingFile(image: pngImage, type: .image, isPNG: true) else { return }

                let newString = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: attributeString)
                newString.replaceCharacters(in: range, with: "")

                self?.newCommentBodyTextView.textView.attributedText = newString

                self?.addFileOnNews(attachmentImage)

                return
            }
        })
    }).disposed(by: bag)
```

You can find more information in https://kostyakulakov.ru/how-to-get-memoji-from-uitextfield-or-uitextview-swift-4/